# Why do I get a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when I run this Python script on Windows but not on Mac OS?

Tags: python, windows, macos, memory

I'm currently working on some geological analysis and came across this error when loading a .tif file of size 65MB, so relatively small. On my Macbook Air, which has 4GB of RAM, I can run the following code with exit code 0; however, on my 16GB Windows desktop, the program exits with an exit code of -1073741819 (0xC0000005), which in the Windows Error Codes represents a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error.

Here's the code that yields the result described above:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import sys, threading
gdal.UseExceptions()


def driver():
    ds = gdal.Open('srtm_21_05.tif')
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    elevation = band.ReadAsArray()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver()
```

I fixed this issue by changing the heap and recursion limits:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.platform[:3] == "win":  # Checks if Windows
        sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)
        threading.stack_size(200000000)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=driver)
        thread.start()
    else:
        driver()
```

Which allows the script to execute, but it ultimately ends up exiting with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005), just as before.

Why does this happen? 65MB is such a small file compared to the memory available on both systems, and as my Macbook shows, the script can execute properly. Why do I need to set these recursion limits for Windows but not Mac?

Comment: Changing the heap and recursion settings is probably only masking the problem temporarily.  Sounds like a bug in the Windows version of GDAL to me.  It might be worth seeing if you can reproduce the problem without Python in the mix.  (And since any such bug is a potential security risk, it may be worth raising this with the developers.)

Comment: An access violation is unrelated to running out of memory. It's due to a bug. Something is trying to read, write, or execute a memory address that's either unallocated or protected. There should be an entry in the event log that tells you which DLL caused the crash, including the offset of the instruction that triggered the exception.